# Python mocking global variable

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using the `sys.modules['cv2'] = Mock()` to mock the OpenCV module but I'm having trouble to use the `assertEqual` to test if a variable has been set up correctly with a global variable. I've simplified the code a bit.
I'm not sure if my mocking is right.

Here is my unit test file:

```
from mock import patch, Mock
sys.modules['cv2'] = Mock()
from MyClass import MyClass
del sys.modules['cv2']

....

def testFunction()
    myObject = MyClass()
    self.assertEqual(myObject.val, ?) # here i don't know how to test the equality
```

and the file `MyClass.py`:

```
import module

val1 = cv2.function(1)
val2 = cv2.function(2)

class MyClass():
    def _init_(self)
        self.val = val1
```

Comment: If you're doing `sys.modules['cv2'] = Mock()` and then `del sys.modules['cv2']` you're deleting `sys.modules['cv2']` (the mocked object) - doesn't make much sense...

Comment: For me it was cleaner to do a delete after mocking. Every opencv function is mock during the import. Maybe i'm wrong

Comment: You're deleting 2 lines after mocking - without using the mocked object

Comment: ok but even by removing the delete line how can i test my equality?

Comment: Well, from your code it's not clear what are you trying to compare...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the best way to do what you want to do is patch `var1`. Anyway, because I'm not sure about what you want to do I'm proposing to you some solutions:

```
from mock import patch

@patch("cv2.function")
def testfunction(mfun):
    mfun.return_value = 200
    import MyClass
    MyObject = MyClass.MyClass()
    assert MyObject.var == 200


import MyClass
print(MyClass.MyClass().var) #my cv2.function(1) stub return -1... but here you can see the real value

@patch("MyClass.var1")
def testfunction(mvar1):
    mvar1 = 300
    MyObject = MyClass.MyClass()
    assert MyObject.var == 300
```

Note that in the first case you MUST import MyClass in `patch` context. The second example just the variable on your module will be patched.

If you must write lot of methods that use a patch like in first example you can use `patch` as class decorator of unittest class: you will patch `cv2` function in all tests.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Chameleon(Mock):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
```

Also have a look at `MagicMock`.