# Can't mock the class method in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I have a class that I try to mock in tests. The class is located in `server/cache.py` and looks like:

```
class Storage(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        # set up connection to a storage engine

    def store_element(self, element, num_of_seconds):
        # store something

    def remove_element(self, element):
        # remove something
```

This class is used in `server/app.py` similar to this one:

```
import cache
STORAGE = cache.Storage('host', 'port')
STORAGE.store_element(1, 5)
```

---

Now the problem arise when I try to mock it in the tests:

```
import unittest, mock
import server.app as application
class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # part1
    def setUp(self):
        # part2
        self.app = application.app.test_client()
```

This clearly does not work during the test, if I can't connect to a storage. So I have to mock it somehow by writing things in 'part1, part2'.

I tried to achieve it with

```
@mock.patch('server.app.cache')  # part 1
mock.side_effect = ... # hoping to overwriting the init function to do nothing
```

But it still tries to connect to a real host. So how can I mock a full class here correctly? P.S. I reviewed [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30531291/how-to-mock-a-redis-client-in-python) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018025/mocking-a-method-outside-of-a-class) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180769/mocking-a-class-mock-or-patch) which look similar to me, but in vain.

Comment: I believe you need to just `@mock.patch('application.cache')`.

Comment: @Will thanks for your interest in my problem. I tried it, but it fails with an error `No module named application`.

Comment: I think you are looking to mock out something in the global space like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668515/python-mocking-global-variable). Because what is happening is that when you import that module, your global will already have that instance. So your mocking is going to be too late. I remember solving this. I would have to dig through some of my code. Try out the link I attached. If it does not work, let me know.